# How to send text throught pc's

Tags: vb.net, text, tcp

Is there any way to send text throught PC's without a client and a server program? Just simply send text from a program to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you don't want to use clients and servers, this is the easiest way to go.
The server is a server that runs in the command prompt, but runs in the background of your program. The server and client won't be visible in any way.
A simple answer with few lines of codes are TCP Communication. This uses the ip addresses of the both computers and establish a server/client connection.

Every communication needs something that hosts it, to achieve this you code the program to contain the following:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Public Class Form1
Dim listener As New TcpListener(8000)
Dim Client As TcpClient
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
listener.Stop()
End Sub
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
Timer1.Start()
listener.Start()
End Sub
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
Dim Data As String = ""
Dim nStart As Integer
Dim nLast As Integer
If listener.Pending = True Then
Client = listener.AcceptTcpClient()
Dim Reader As New StreamReader(Client.GetStream)
While Reader.Peek > -1
Data &= Convert.ToChar(Reader.Read()).ToString
End While
If Not Data = "" Then
msgbox("This is the data recieved: " & Data)
End If
End If
End Sub
End Class
```

This will open a "TCPListener" on the localhost port 8000. Whenever a client sends data to the listener, the text of the textbox Textbox1 to the data sent.

To send data to the server, use the following code:

```
Option Explicit On
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Public Class Form1
Dim Client As TcpClient
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Try
//Ip to the local or remote, forwarded server. 127.0.0.1 is localhost - the same machine.
Client = New TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 8000)
Dim Writer As New StreamWriter(Client.GetStream())
Writer.Write("Hello World!")
Writer.Flush()
Catch ex As Exception
MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

This will, when Button1 is pressed, try to send the data/string "Hello World!" to the server.

This could be combined into one by having the application set up as following:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Public Class Form1
Dim listener As New TcpListener(8000)
Dim Client As TcpClient
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
listener.Stop()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
Timer1.Start()
listener.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
Dim Data As String = ""
Dim nStart As Integer
Dim nLast As Integer
If listener.Pending = True Then
Client = listener.AcceptTcpClient()
Dim Reader As New StreamReader(Client.GetStream)
While Reader.Peek > -1
Data &= Convert.ToChar(Reader.Read()).ToString
End While
If Not Data = "" Then
'Change the string
End If
TextBox1.Text = Data
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Try
//This has to be the address to the remote 
Client = New TcpClient("xx.xx.xx.xx", 8000)
Dim Writer As New StreamWriter(Client.GetStream())
Writer.Write(TextBox2.Text)
Writer.Flush()
Catch ex As Exception
MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

To extend this and make it useable in a real application, use a backgroundworker to simply make the server and client run on another thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use socket or pipes, i can only think of files, which is more pc to pc than program to program.

Comment: I tried lots of codes but nothing worked. Could you show me how to make a program the server and the client at the same time? I would like to send (a lot of) text through the programs but I don't really know how